# Публикация приложения в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Решил опубликовать приложение в Google Play, но уже пару дней оно висит в таком состоянии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя у меня и знакомых такого раньше вроде не было. 
Кто знает, с чем это может быть связанно и сколько примерно по времени ждать?

Comment: Судя по официальному источнику [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282)
это нормально. Нужно ждать пока перейдет на следующий этап.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С некоторых пор приложения могут проверяться долго. По [утверждению](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282) гугла до 7 дней. Однако, известны случаи по 10 и более дней. Это связано с тем, что модерация Google Play устроена максимально плохо. Google объясняет это заботой о качестве приложений и защите юезров от вирусов и прочих бед.

О примерах долгих проверок и безпричинных банов приложений и аккаунтов разработчиков можете почитать в чате в телеграмме: https://t.me/android_developers_ban

---

ИМХО в Google Play лучше вообще приложение не выкладывать.

Comment: Уважаемый ЮрийСПб! А где же публиковать тогда?

Comment: @Anton, в сторонних магазинах) В Amazon AppStore например. Есть ещё штук 10 разных. Но да, аудитория там в разы меньше и надо быть прошаренным юзером чтобы скачать магазин сторонний, его поставить и через него поставить приложение. Гугл всячески защищает свою монополию. С другой стороны, если выкладывать в Google Play, то рано или поздно приложение и аккаунт разработчика будет забанен. Такие дела. В течении месяца постараюсь вспомнить и добавить сюда длинный список статей про произвол гугла в отношении разработчиков.

Comment: Уважаемый ЮрийСПб! Спасибо Вам за информацию!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб интересно было бы почитать,  буду ждать ваш список статей.

Comment: Проще на 4pda заливать)) критика обеспечена :)